# Race-condition between @SubscribeMapping and ChannelInterceptorAdapter.preSend

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

In my Spring Boot 1.5.9 application with Spring Websockets, web-socket subscriptions are intercepted with an implementation of [ChannelInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/ChannelInterceptorAdapter.html):

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHelper.accessor(message);
    StompCommand command = accessor.getCommand();

    if (null != command) {
        StompHelper.authentication(message, tokenHandler);

        switch (command) {

        case SUBSCRIBE:
            this.stompHandler.subscribe(message);
            break;
        case UNSUBSCRIBE:
            this.stompHandler.unsubscribe(message);
            break;
        // ...
        }
    }
    return super.preSend(message, channel);
}
```

which captures the subscriber and destination so subscriber-specific messages can be sent. In the web-socket controller, the `@SubscribeMapping` implementation publishes initialization data to the subscriber. But the `@SubscribeMapping` and `ChannelInterceptorAdapter.preSend` are invoked in different threads, so occasionally the `@SubscribeMapping` executes before the completion of `ChannelInterceptorAdapter.preSend` which results in the subscriber not getting the initialization data.

This seems like a Spring Websocket design problem, but is there an (elegant-ish) work-around?

**Update**: submitted a bug: [SPR-16323](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16323)

Comment: Maybe file a bug on it?

Comment: Yes, @chrylis; the Spring team monitors these tags but if there's no solution I'll open an issue.

Comment: That's a good point, and I added [spring] since I know that at least a couple of them primarily browse that one.